# Unexpected expiration date for Amazon RDS SSL certificate

Tags: postgresql, ssl, amazon-web-services, x509, amazon-rds

Amazon is rotating its CA for its RDS instances, and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) they say that the updated certificate can be found [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem). However, if I download that file and inspect it with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`, I see that the expiration date is April 4, 2015.

This doesn't seem right; shouldn't the updated certificate have a later expiration date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that file is a certificate bundle, containing several CA certificates.  I'm guessing your command picked up the first one by default.  Every ----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- represents a different CA

I believe this page has a script that will parse the bundle.  http://blog.swwomm.com/2015/02/importing-new-rds-ca-certificate-into.html